# How can I extract this number from a weather api to convert it in Farenheit?

Tags: javascript, api, converters, openweathermap

This is the function to take the temperature data from a weather API (among other data):

```
displayWeather: function (data) {
    const { name } = data;
    const { icon, description } = data.weather[0];
    const { temp, humidity } = data.main;
    const { speed } = data.wind;
    document.querySelector(".city").innerText = "El tiempo en " + name;
    document.querySelector(".icon").src =
        "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
    document.querySelector(".description").innerText = description;
    document.querySelector(".temp").innerText = Math.trunc(temp) + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".humidity").innerText =
        "Humedad: " + humidity + "% ";
    document.querySelector(".wind").innerText =
        "Velocidad del viento: " + speed + " km/h";
```

The temp is the value I need to convert in Farenheit. The script is already done but I always get a NaN. I know there's a "°C" after that number, but even when I remove this to extract only the number I continue getting NaN.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Exactly what value is stored in `temp`? Where are you trying to convert it?

Comment: Use `parseInt(temp)`. It will ignore any extra characters after the number.,

Comment: @Barmar according to the [API docs](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON), `main.temp` is already a number

Comment: If you want the temperature in Fahrenheit, you can specify `units=imperial` when making your request to the API. See https://openweathermap.org/current#data

Comment: @Phil Since he's displaying in Celsius here, I suspect his converter is running later, and processing the `innerText`, which has `°C` appended.

Comment: @Barmar makes sense but I'd highly recommend caching the original data response and working with that instead of pulling values from the DOM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I finally solve the problem but figuring out which part was wrong and I discovered I wasn't using the correct line of code to extract the data and set it in the correct place.

Before:

```
 C = document.getElementById("ID").value;
```

Correct line:

```
C = document.querySelector(".temp").innerText;
```

Now that line of code finally takes the temp and I can turn it into Farenheit with:

```
F = (C * 9) / 5 + 32;
```

Sorry for the silly question. Now I just have to figure out how can I add the + "°C"

Comment: This code doesn't appear anywhere in your question

Comment: @Phil I know, sorry, that's the code from the script to convert celsius into farenheit and viceversa, I just thought the problem was in the main.temp not being a number or something.

Answer (score 0):

change your openweathermap api's units from imperial to metric

For temperature in Fahrenheit use units=imperial
For temperature in Celsius use units=metric